# Python: Apply function every 100 rows of large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

I have a large dataset of approximately 25,000 rows. I am trying to extract elevation data for every one of my observations. However, I can only make 100 requests at a time. This means that I need approximately 250 splits to make individual requests!

I was wondering if there is an efficient way of doing this?

I came across this condition but I wouldn't want to repeat this 250 times and apply the function each time.

```
first_hun = pd.DataFrame()
rest = pd.DataFrame()

if df.shape[0] > 100: # len(df) > 100 would also work
    first_hun = df[:100]
    rest = df[100:]
```

In a "sketchy" way, this is what I am attempting:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    
    # split df every 100 rows
        # apply elevation function (my_function)
        # store the 100 elevation values
        
    # concat the 250 elevation values so they're in the same list
    
# add list to original df
```

Comment: `df.loc[[i for i in range(df.shape[0]) if i%100==0]]` if dataframe has normal numerical range index values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the test let's create the source DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(101, 122, 2)})
```

Assume that your function to generate the elevation, for a subset of the source
DataFrame is:

```
def myFun(src, txt):
    return txt + src.A.astype(str)
```

Then you can generate the new colum as a concatenation of consecutive
calls for subsets of *df* as:

```
tt = 'ABC'
n = len(tt)
df['Elev'] = pd.concat([ myFun(df[i::n], x) for i, x in enumerate(tt) ])
```

Details:

- `tt` is the source string - a list of letters to prepend to the source column.
- `n` is the step with which to generate each source subset of *df*.
- `for i, x in...` retrieves consecutive letters from *tt* and their indices.
  *i* is the number of the source subset and at the same time the starting
  point in *df* and *x* is the letter to prepend to the
  result.
- `df[i::n]` selects a subset of the source DataFrame.
- `pd.concat` concatenates partial results.

The result is:

```
      A  Elev
0   101  A101
1   103  B103
2   105  C105
3   107  A107
4   109  B109
5   111  C111
6   113  A113
7   115  B115
8   117  C117
9   119  A119
10  121  B121
```

As you can see, values starting with *A* result from the first
call, values starting with *B* from the second and so on.

If for any reason you can not use a list comprehension, you can
do it in an "ordinary" loop, something like:

```
res = []
for i, x in enumerate(tt):
    res.append(myFun(df[i::n], x))
df['Elev'] = pd.concat(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a series that only increments every 100 values and use that to group the dataframe. I'm using a smaller example to fit on screen and showing a few processing options.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"FOO":list(range(50))})

# using each group
for idx, grp in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//5):
    print(idx, grp.FOO.values)

# using a pandas chained method
result = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//5).sum()
print(result)

# applying your own function to the group dataframes
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//5).apply(lambda df: print(df.FOO.values))
```